# iOS Swift: Local persistence with CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I'm using CloudKit to fetch/store data but would also like to have a local persistence layer. Does CloudKit offer any kind of local storage capabilities? Or should I use NSUserDefaults (NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no mechanism for cashing data locally in CloudKit, you have to do that yourself. 
I can suggest you to take a look at [EVCloudKitDao](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao) which is a convenience library for CloudKit that has support for local cashing to a file.

Comment: Can you recommend any articles or resources for learning more about local storage with CloudKit?

Comment: checked out  EVCloudKitDao, wow, you are a ninja :D you are **not** using any `Core Data`, but am I understand good, that you have classes defined in the bundle, and with reflection you load in, instantiate, set value? wow, that is tough, WHY reflection and not Core Data? basically Core Data do the same, with less boilerplate code ;-)

Comment: I'm using reflection for getting and setting all the values from a regular Object. So the only thing you need to do is define properties in an object. EVCloudKitDao will then handle the rest. It will make sure that all properties will be added to a CKRecord and the other way around. Storing to Core data would be an option but then still you need to parse from and to a CKRecord. I decided to store my data locally in files using NSCoding instead of writing it to a database.

Comment: Defining properties in an object is still easier than maintaining Core Data. Besides than you only need to use EVCloudKitDao and  you do not need any boiler plate code at all. This was the leanest way to use CloudKit that I could think of. See the code sample at https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao#how-to-use-the-evcloudkitdata  that is all you need for a table with news items, including push notifications for changes

Comment: funny, I have my own ' EVCloudKitDao', but I call it 'Utility'. And it does the same as your code. Your learning curve concluded in reflection based solution, my in Core Data based. If it is up and running who cares. Maintaining Core Data is easy, if you are over Core Data steep learning curve. To add an attribute or relationship in Core Data editor needs exact the same number of key press as add a property to a source file.

Comment: but still, Core Data support some fancy feature i.e. `rollback`, user does interactions, it generates operations, client put operations into a serial queue, and if CloudKit returns error, (some serious, not repeat 3 sec latter), then all the following operations already on queue will `rollback`. Do you have similar?

Comment: It looks like your Utility is using Core Data as the main source and CloudKit as it's backup. I work the other way around. I only save data locally if the save to CloudKit was successful. Besides that I have a complete integration of handling the data from subscriptions. With direct notifications in the code where it's used (You probably do that through Core Data plus a NSFetchedResultsController?)

Answer (score 0):

No caching built in CloudKit, anyway when you implement one Keep in mind to cache only the system fields to restore and synch with CloudKit again
check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35355916/1787109